# Exchangelib - How to save the most recent attachment from a specific subject line

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am trying to read and save the most recent email attachments with specific email subject. I know how to filter the email by the subject line **OR** the receive time. But I don't know how to combine this two requests. Can you please let me know if you have a better idea to resolve this?

I only know how to read the most recent email using this

```
for item in a.inbox.children:
    for e in item.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
        for attachment in e.attachments:
             ...
```

I know how to get the specific subject email:

```
for item in a.inbox.children.filter(subject = 'this is my subject line'):
    for attachment in item.attachments:
          ....
```

How could I obtain the most recent email attachment from a specific subject line?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "most recent attachment", but attachments do have a `last_modified_time` field: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/a695bda1edd9a574532bd099fe0c19968a5c5be4/exchangelib/attachments.py#L42

So you can do something like:

```py
last_modified_attachment = sorted(
    item.attachments, 
    key=lambda i: i.last_modified_time
)[-1]
```

For each item in your search, this would select the attachment that was last modified. But you may find that they were all modified at almost the same time, if `last_modified_time` means the time when the attachment was created in EWS.

For item attachments (attachments of type `ItemAttachment`), you could also dig into one of the datetime fields on `attachment.item` and sort by one of those.

Comment: Thanks Erik! Most recent means the first email order by the newest receive date. order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]